# CSS styling, float:right and keeping the left text to a restricted width

Tags: html, css, width

I'm trying to replicate the following table of contents:

[image]

You can see my attempt [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hBJnm/) and see the problem: I don't know how to keep the chapter titles restricted to a specific width so that they don't wander over to the page numbers. I've tried things like `width:250px` and `margin-right:30px;` and `padding-right:30px;`, but to no avail.

Here's some of the code:

```
.conts {
    font-size:80%;
    text-align:justify;
    text-indent:-1em;
    margin-left:1em;
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
}

    <div style="text-align:center;font-size:80%">CHAP. IX.</div>
    <div class="conts"><span><em>Of the different Degrees of Virtue and Vice</em>, <em>and the methods of estimating them</em>. <em>Of Difficulties attending the practice of Virtue the use of Trial and Discipline in forming reasonable Beings to Virtue</em>, <em>and the Essentials of a good and bad Character</em>.</span><span style="float:right;">p. 200</span>
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `p` to wrap the text instead of a `span` element, assign some fixed width to `p` and `float` that to the `left`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V5yDj/)

```
.conts {
    font-size:80%;
    text-align:justify;
    text-indent:-1em;
    margin-left:1em;
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
    width: 600px;
}

.conts p {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}

.conts span {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

---

If you want to `position` the number at the end of the line, use `position: absolute;` wrapped inside `position: relative;` container.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/V5yDj/1/)

Comment: The OP is trying to set page number at end of line not in first line.

Comment: @C-Link Well, I thought he was asking for the floats, well, again I've shared a solution for that too :)

Answer (score 0):

First. change all this code `<span style="float:right;"> Page number here </span>` into `<p>Page number</p>`. then change your CSS like this.

```
.entry {
    width: 450px;
    padding-left: 90px;
}
strong {
    font-variant:small-caps;
    font-weight:normal;
}
.conts {
    width:100%;
}
.conts span {
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    font-size:80%;
    text-align:justify;
    text-indent:-1em;
    margin-left:1em;
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
}

.conts p {
    float:right;
    width:10%;
    font-size:80%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Last, add `<br clear="all"/>` after `<p>Page Number</p>`. hope this help :)

**[See Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/edisutrisno/hBJnm/7/)**

Comment: It's still not perfect as he want. See the picture.

Comment: The problem is he using div. so the page number can not align at the bottom of content.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `padding-right:100px;` to the contents and `margin-right:-100px;` to the floated page number. That should make sure the full contents are correctly made to stay a certain width while pulling your page numbers out of that space and into the right margin.

Comment: I'm on my iPad and jsFiddle isn't playing nice, but I just tested it in your example code and it worked.

Comment: I tried it with one of the lines, and it didn't work well: http://jsfiddle.net/hBJnm/8/

Comment: You put the padding on the left instead of the right. Here's a proper fork of your code, I've adjusted the space to 50px since 100px was overkill, and I've gone and made the page numbers a class as well for you: http://jsfiddle.net/davmillar/VGbbz/

Answer (score -1):

wrap all of the chapters up into one main div. Float that left, width 80% (or whatever works). then wrap your page numbers into a second div, and float that right with a width of 20% or less, depending on your margins. MAKE SURE YOU GIVE YOUR WRAPPER DIV (or whatever div you wrapped the entire code in) A WIDTH OR THE WIDTHS YOU ASSIGN TO INSIDE DIVS WILL NOT WORK.

Comment: For recreating that page, this works if done manually and knowing how many lines come between each page number. For further use, though, this method is too manual/specific, and it also breaks the readability of the text in the absence of CSS.